# Selenium Drivers click on elements but does not redirect to next page

Tags: java, selenium, automation

functionName is the linktext i need to click, the script executes the click but it does not redirect.
Same script redirects when executed on other system.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText(functionName)));

        WebElement functionAnchor = driver.findElement(By.linkText(functionName));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            functionAnchor.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (ElementNotVisibleException e) {
            // Wait for stabilizing the rendered page
            Thread.sleep(500);
            // Scroll Into View the function link and perform click to avoid
            // "Element Not Visible for clicking" error
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", functionAnchor);
            functionAnchor.click();
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
```

[as you can see in the pic first i need to click on "More..." link which is working and it opens up the panel in which i need to click on purchase requisition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnN5z.png)

Comment: If there is more than one element exist then it will not click.So,make sure that the xpath or id you used to find that element should be unique.Also make sure that it is not coming under any iframe.

Comment: the xpath is uniquely identifying the link which needs to be clicked

Comment: Use this code before where you are trying to click:`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(functionAnchor));`

Comment: Didn't change anything since the issue it that the element is getting clicked and still it is not getting redirected

Answer (score 0):

**Analysis:**

There are couple possible reasons which can lead to your issue:

1. The page or the area where the link inside are loaing when you click on it, at that time point browser is busy on rendering element to page, it has no idle resource to react your click.
2. The page or the area where the link inside are loaing when you click on it, developer use javascript to register click event to the link in page loading process, at that time point, the javascript snippet have not executed yet or not all compelte which lead the click event not register to the link, so there is no click event to react your click.

The reason why you can pass on other system, the possbile reason is browser more fast, network more fast, etc.

**Solution:**

Add sleep() before click and run multiple times on each system, when all pass, it hints your wait is not sufficient, at least on this system. Remove sleep() and modify wait condition to make wait can more close to end of page loading

Comment: i added sleep upto 5 seconds still it would click and not redirect

Comment: for debug purpose, try 15 or 20 seconds, could you give relevant html code

Comment: can you give a screenshot, half is page look like, half is relevant html code? And did you confirm you code will only find that one link?  If selenium not throw NoSuchElement exception, means there is possible one or more matched link on the page, if find more than one and the first one is you wanted, manual click on the first one to see what will hapen.

Comment: there is only 1 link as per my xpath and it can be seen that it is getting clicked  still it does not load the page ill attach the screenshots

Comment: Selenium can find the correct link and you sleep 15-20 seconds before click it.  It's not reasonable the page not redirect. I don't think the page not complete loading or bind click event to the link even after 15-20 seconds. If so your page is too slow. Can you give the relevant html code of link? Did you check the link inside a frame or not?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) clearly mentions that the **`ExpectedConditions`** clause which you are using i.e. **`visibilityOfElementLocated`** takes care of the `expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible` but it doesn't covers if the element is **`Displayed`** and **`Enabled`**.

Next as we are trying to invoke **`click()`** method on the element so instead of **`visibilityOfElementLocated`** we will be using **`elementToBeClickable`**.

- **`Element is Clickable` - it is Displayed and Enabled.**

If we use the **`ExpectedConditions`** clause as **`elementToBeClickable`**, instead of using **`sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)`** we can directly invoke the **`click()`** method and get rid of the **`Thread.sleep(500)`** too.

Comment: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText(functionName)));

still the issue exists , i.e. it click on the link but does not load the page

Answer (score 0):

I happen to run into click() problems myself too.

Which browser and which version are you using?

Firefox and Internet Explorer has this problem with CLICK and I used JavaScript to click on the found web element.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("webElementId"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: i am using google chrome Version 61.0.3163.91
i used the above code still the issue persist, i.e. it clicked on the link but landed on the same page did not navigate to next page

Comment: For chrome version 61 u should use chrome driver 2.32 and Selenium 3.5.0 or similar. and are you sure the link works ok when manually clicked? and the webElementId is not duplicate?

Comment: i am using Chrome driver 2.32 and selenium 3.5.3 and yes when i click manually it does load.

Comment: Verify that the webElementId is unique.. so when you find it there should be no mistake. And try to click it with the JavaScript code given above. And also use debugger and be sure to check element found is the correct one and the javascript click command works. Let me know what happens :D

Comment: yes the webElementId is unique, nd i hav used the JavaScript code given above to click still the issue persist.

Comment: Did u debug it? Is the element being found? Was the click script executed? what is the next line of code after the click? maybe it is doing something quickly before the click function  switches to new page

Comment: yes  i did debug it, the click got executed as well. the next line of code is a wait condition wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(getTitle())); it waits for the title of pages which is supposed to be loaded and fails with timeout exception since the the page with necessary title never loads

Comment: Please share your latest code and if possible URL to test or sample project

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue, where it was clicking an element but it was not redirecting to the next page and was not getting an exception also. I tried with Actions class, Javascript executor, Robot class and all the wait statements, but I was not getting the result. This solution worked for me.

```
try {
      //Next page element
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='web']/label/span[contains(text(), 'Congratulations!')]")).click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
    //current page element which is not redirecting after performing click operation
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-main-container']/button")).click();
        }
```

***You have to try to interact with an element on the next page and use the XPath for the element in the try block and the XPath for the element which is not redirected to next page in a catch block.***